# Unable to share AWS S3 bucket by Canonical ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have IAM account of AWS with full administration access. I create another IAM account and don't give any permission to this account.

Then I created a bucket in my own account and try to grant access to the newly created by using the canonical id(New Account).

But as I enter the canonical id in my AWS S3 console and select the permissions and click save button. I didn't see anything in response and the bucket doesn't share with the newly created account.

I create this new account for my Laravel developer.

Thank you

Comment: You can use AWS s3 policies by easily and securely. Here is the webpage that you can create policies via GUI; https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: *"the bucket doesn't share with the newly created account."*  What does this mean, exactly?  A bucket will not appear in the console of another account, if that is what you are anticipating.